# Why C# ArrayList doesn't have Resize method?

Tags: c#, arraylist, resize

Coming from C++, it's very weird to find that C# `ArrayList` doesn't have `Resize(count)` method? 
Why? Am I missing something?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you still using ArrayList at all? Prefer the generic `List<T>` type.

Comment: In my experience this method is rarely necessary. When do you want to add constant elements to the end of a collection?

Comment: C# is somehow very different from C++, so don't treat them equally. And don't try to use any STL thing in C#.

Comment: Yes, I should be using `List<T>`. Usecase: I want to make it the same size as another list. Example: actual list of data and a list of temp-data for processing actual data. In a way yes, I think you're right: `Resize` is less useful in C#, but I think I still need it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are three separate operations you might wish to perform:

- Changing the *capacity* of the `ArrayList`. This is achievable through [`ArrayList.Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.capacity.aspx) and [`List<T>.Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx)
- Changing the *actual count* of the list by trimming some elements. This is achievable through [`ArrayList.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.removerange.aspx) and [`List<T>.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx).
- Changing the *actual count* of the list by adding some elements. This is achievable through [`ArrayList.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange.aspx) and [`List<T>.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx). (As of .NET 3.5, you can use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) to very easily come up with a sequence of the right length.)

(I mention `List<T>` as unless you're *really* stuck on .NET 1.1, you'd be better off using the generic collections.)

If you want to perform some other operation, please specify it. Personally I'm glad that these three operations are separate. I can't think of any cases in my own experience where I've wanted to add or remove elements without knowing which I'd actually be doing.

Comment: I use std::vector::resize all the time. My current case: I have a vector with data and a vector with cache/temp-data for processing that primary data. So all I want to do is: cacheList.Count = dataList.Count; I don't really care if elements have to be added or removed.

Comment: @Paulinus: I think you'd have to give more details about exactly what you're doing... it's entirely possible that you'd simply use a different approach in C#. You shouldn't try to write C# as if it were C++ (or vice versa).

Comment: I few year later I come back to my own question still wondering how you do it in C#.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis: Well last time you asked, I said you'd need to give more details of what you were doing... so I still can't give any more information until I have more context.

Comment: My use case: I have a cache (a list) which a I used for processing other lists (with varying sizes). I need to resize the cache before processing a list. I have two options: 1) Clear it, then set Capacity, and then use Add. Problem with this is that I need to check whether current Capacity is smaller than what I need. So it's two calls and an if. 2) Use RemoveRange or AddRange. So it's two calls plus if-else-if-else. In C++ this can be done with "rezise" or "reserve". Single call.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis: Well it's not clear whether you *actually* want to clear it or not - that makes a huge difference. If you're still bothered, I suggest you ask a new question with more details - I'm still finding it hard to tell *exactly* what semantics you want.

Comment: People keep saying "don't think about C# like it's C++", but I don't get that part - it should be the same principle: try to reduce the amount of reallocations in order to reduce change of memory fragmentation.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis: Again, without the details - which should be in a new question - it's very hard to be concrete about this. But the advice to avoid thinking about C# in the same way as C++ is still valid, particularly in terms of how you handle memory... they're handled *massively* differently.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Generic List<> ([System.Collections.Generic.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)) for this. It operates in constant amortized time. Or you can use the `ArrayList.Capacity` for your purpose.

Comment: `std::vector` does the same, and it still has `resize`. So this is not a good explanation.

Comment: Am I missing something or is it totally out of context?

Comment: As far as I understand setting ArrayList.Capacity is equivalent to std::vector::reserve. Setting ArrayList.Count would be what I want, but ArrayList.Count is read-only.